# Collapse posts when flag has been handled in 10K tools

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, user-interface, 10k-tools

When I use the 10k tools to handle flags, I lose track of which posts I've handled because there is no visual change to the post once I've handle the flag.

Would it be possible to minimise the post after I've handled the flag? This seems to happen when I handle closure flags, but not for any other kind.

I appreciate I can refresh the list and remove the posts I've handled, but this is inefficient.

---

To give a visual example: I've handled the flag on **one** of these questions below.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A recent change to the 10K tools now causes posts to become grey when the flags have been handled.

This is good enough for me. Post-collapsing was just one way to solve the underlying problem of understanding which flags I've handled.

Comment: I'd much rather see collapsing, but I suppose it's okay for now.

Comment: @Joe I agree. But after many months of waiting, this change is still very welcome and probably good enough.